# Installing gcc from Kubuntu DVD

Tags: installation, kubuntu, gcc

I am having a hard time with a Kubuntu 12.04 install that does not have an internet connection. In order to build the ethernet driver, I need `gcc`. I installed from the DVD, and I have `gcc-4.7-base` installed but that does not provide a `gcc` executable? Should I just make a symlink? How should I install `gcc` otherwise?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Here are some attempts to install GCC. The CD-ROM repo is enabled in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and the full DVD is in the drive.

```
shelly@neptune:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcc-4.6 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libgomp1 libquadmath0 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  gcc-multilib autoconf automake1.9 libtool flex bison gcc-doc gcc-4.6-multilib libmudflap0-4.6-dev gcc-4.6-doc gcc-4.6-locales libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libquadmath0-dbg libmudflap0-dbg binutils-gold glibc-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc gcc-4.6 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libgomp1 libquadmath0 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/13.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 33.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main libquadmath0 amd64 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main gcc-4.6 amd64 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main gcc amd64 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main libc-dev-bin amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.2.0-23.36
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main libc6-dev amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main manpages-dev all 3.35-0.1ubuntu1
  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/g/gcc-4.6/libquadmath0_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/g/gcc-4.6/gcc-4.6_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/gcc_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc-dev-bin_2.15-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.2.0-23.36_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-dev_2.15-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/m/manpages/manpages-dev_3.35-0.1ubuntu1_all.deb  File not found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
shelly@neptune:~$ 
shelly@neptune:~$ 
shelly@neptune:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.6 gcc gcc-4.6 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libdpkg-perl libgomp1 libquadmath0 libstdc++6-4.6-dev linux-libc-dev manpages-dev patch
Suggested packages:
  debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-4.6-multilib gcc-4.6-doc libstdc++6-4.6-dbg gcc-multilib autoconf automake1.9 libtool flex bison gcc-doc gcc-4.6-multilib libmudflap0-4.6-dev gcc-4.6-locales libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libquadmath0-dbg
  libmudflap0-dbg binutils-gold glibc-doc libstdc++6-4.6-doc diffutils-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.6 gcc gcc-4.6 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libdpkg-perl libgomp1 libquadmath0 libstdc++6-4.6-dev linux-libc-dev
  manpages-dev patch
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/22.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 62.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main libquadmath0 amd64 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main libc-dev-bin amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.2.0-23.36
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main libc6-dev amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main gcc-4.6 amd64 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main gcc amd64 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main libstdc++6-4.6-dev amd64 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main g++-4.6 amd64 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main g++ amd64 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main libdpkg-perl all 1.16.1.2ubuntu7
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main patch amd64 2.6.1-3
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main dpkg-dev all 1.16.1.2ubuntu7
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main build-essential amd64 11.5ubuntu2
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main fakeroot amd64 1.18.2-1
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main libalgorithm-diff-perl all 1.19.02-2
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl amd64 0.04-2build2
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main libalgorithm-merge-perl all 0.08-2
  File not found
Err cdrom://Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)/ precise/main manpages-dev all 3.35-0.1ubuntu1
  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/g/gcc-4.6/libquadmath0_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc-dev-bin_2.15-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.2.0-23.36_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-dev_2.15-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/g/gcc-4.6/gcc-4.6_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/gcc_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/g/gcc-4.6/libstdc++6-4.6-dev_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/g/gcc-4.6/g++-4.6_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/g++_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/d/dpkg/libdpkg-perl_1.16.1.2ubuntu7_all.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/p/patch/patch_2.6.1-3_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg-dev_1.16.1.2ubuntu7_all.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/b/build-essential/build-essential_11.5ubuntu2_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.18.2-1_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/liba/libalgorithm-diff-perl/libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.19.02-2_all.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/liba/libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl/libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-2build2_amd64.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/liba/libalgorithm-merge-perl/libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-2_all.deb  File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120423)]/pool/main/m/manpages/manpages-dev_3.35-0.1ubuntu1_all.deb  File not found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
shelly@neptune:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       15570572 2675916  12113448  19% /
udev              829680       4    829676   1% /dev
tmpfs             336752     816    335936   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none              841872      80    841792   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda6      454024280 6869848 424428648   2% /home
/dev/sr0         3401516 3401516         0 100% /media/apt
shelly@neptune:~$ ls /media/
apt/        .directory  .hidden     
shelly@neptune:~$ ls /media/apt/
autorun.inf  boot  casper  cdromupgrade  dists  doc  efi  install  isolinux  md5sum.txt  pics  pool  preseed  README.diskdefines  ubuntu  wubi.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc-4.7-base` contains only the common files for all languages and libraries available in gcc. It does not contain `gcc` compiler itself. If you want to install `gcc` from CD, insert it and issue the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential`, it'll give you `gcc` and `g++`(C++ compiler).

Comment: @dotancohen, when I boot from my Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD, it has `gcc` installed. If the Kubuntu DVD doesn't have those packages then you can always note down those dependencies(`gcc gcc-4.6 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libgomp1 libquadmath0 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev`) and manually download them from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) then use `dpkg -i` to install them.