# Motherboards for new Ubuntu install

Tags: hardware

I will be installing Kubuntu on 4 computers for a small business network. Due to [previous problems](https://askubuntu.com/a/159031/23087) with Ubuntu on recent motherboards, I would like to know which of the following motherboards can be reasonably expected to work out of the box with Kubuntu 12.04 LTS or Kubuntu 12.10. These are the only motherboards in our price range from the supplier, unfortunately:

- Asus P8H61-M LX R2.0
- Asus P8H61-M LE R2.0
- Asus P8H61-I R2.0
- Gigabyte GA-H61M-D2H
- Gigabyte GA-H77M-D3H

It seems that the Ubuntu Hardware Compatibility List website is no longer maintained, and I cannot find any official information about these motherboards on Linux in general or Ubuntu in particular.

Comment: H77M-D3H network adapter doesn't work (Cable unplugged but buth green and orange LED are lighting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We went with the Gigabyte GA-H77M-D3H, which works fine.