# Where do I find drivers for the Realtek 8111E LAN controller?

Tags: asus, lan, drivers

I just bought an ASUS P8H61-M LX motherboard. This motherboard comes with a Windows driver package to enable the onboard ethernet port. My troubles with this board are documented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157969/dhcp-not-working-on-new-install/158036#158036) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157651/no-internet-in-12-04-or-11-10-neither-on-wired-nor-wireless). After installing Windows the LAN did not work either, but after installing the supplied driver disk in Windows the LAN was then enabled.

I have been googling for the Linux driver but cannot find it. I see that others have used this motherboard in Linux, so apparently it is possible. I wrote to ASUS but I do not expect a reply for 48-72 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your motherboard has a [Realtek RTL8111E](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.realtek.com%2Fproducts%2FproductsView.aspx%3FLangid%3D1%26PFid%3D5%26Level%3D5%26Conn%3D4%26ProdID%3D239&ei=ZHfwT6qFGsj-2QWYvKSwAQ&usg=AFQjCNE2NV4l5BThm4_mMix7eImAETkltQ&sig2=WCWhlZSWayxQ46OaZTfaPw) Gigabit Ethernet controller.

The driver built-into the Linux kernel should work, but if you wish to install the latest driver supplied by the manufacturer, [you can get it here](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2).

1. Open the downloaded file in Archive Manager, and extract it, e.g to the Downloads folder as shown below:

   [image]
2. Open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`, and change to that directory, e.g. `cd Downloads/r8168-8.031.00`
3. Type `sudo ./autorun.sh` and that should take care of removing the old driver and installing the new one.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded `LINUX driver for kernel 3.x and 2.6.x and 2.4.x` from all five of the mirrors, not a single one got over 10 KiB before disconnecting. I'll keep trying.

Comment: @dotancohen: if it keeps failing let me know, I have a copy and can upload it somewhere for you.

Comment: I would appreciate that, I cannot get past 10 KiB. My Gmail address has the same username as my SE account :)

Comment: @dotancohen: try the "unofficial" [mirror hosted at google code](http://code.google.com/p/r8168/downloads/detail?name=r8168-8.031.00.tar.bz2&can=2&q=)

Comment: Thanks. I see that is for the 8186, will that still work? How can I verify exactly which controller is on the motherboard from within Ubuntu itself, without relying on the packaging. I would really like to verify first.

Comment: It's the same family - same driver. That's the one I dLd from rtl (see screenshOT closely). Use `lshw -c network` to check.

Answer (score 1):

The driver can be found [here](http://www.twm-kd.com/linux/realtek-rtl81688111e-and-ubuntu-linux/) as well as the answer as how to install it. The ASUS P8H61-M LX motherboard comes with the Realtek® 8111E , 1 x Gigabit LAN Controller(s) therefore the proper driver needs to be updated.

Comment: The current driver from Realtek includes an `autorun.sh` file that takes careof all the manual steps outlined in the blog post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the lack of drivers for this motherboard's NIC. I expand on the problem more [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/159031/23087).